# Mysql stored proc returning 500 empty rows

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have a table (vendTable) that contains venName and venDesc.  Both varchar(30) NOT NULL.  Contains 500 rows that get refreshed everyday.  The table is truncated and reloaded daily.  No indexes.

Doing a "select venName , venDesc from vendTable;" will give me 500 rows.

I wrapped this 1 sql statment into a stored procedure, getVendors.

When I do a "call getVendors();"  it returns 500 rows of good data.

It's been running fine for weeks, but today, the getVendors() proc returned 500 empty rows.  Not NULL, but just empty, but 500 of them.  No errors, no warnings.  I run the 1 line qry, and it returns as expected.  I drop and recreate the proc, but still the same empty result occurs.  We created an additional proc with the same code, but different name, and no luck.  Table diagnostics and checks for errors came back fine.  Repair came back with no errors found.  Character sets and collations are fine.  Nothing in the log files.

After a bit, the procedure was working again, returning good data.

I have 3 similar mysql data bases on 3 different hosts.  And they run fine.

Has anyone seen this before?  Anything else to look at? Thanks in advance.  It's mysql 5.0.95 running on CentOS 5.8

Comment: So the import process inserted 500 rows with empty strings for data?

Comment: No.  Input data was checked as is fine.  Sql statment returns valid data.  Proc does not.